# Why do my imessages go to all the ipads in the house

Tags: ios

Since switching to ios 7  all my imessages go to my daughters ipad and my husbands plus my name shows up as the sender from his ipad.  How do I stop this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have configured the accounts in that way. Check the iMessage configuration on all devices. Since iOS 7 asks for the account data after updating, this might have been introduced after updating.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each person's iPad is using a separate account.   If they are all linked to one account, they will all receive the same messages.   Normally, you would want each person in the house to have their own account (Apple ID).

-this is recommended, but not a necessary if youd like to keep tabs on younger iusers. I resolved this problem by going into my settings, clicking messages, then it told me I could be reached on 3 devices. I unclicked my wifes # and daughters ipod email. once these were disabled I stopped getting their messages and vise versa..